# How to fetch all options of dropdown values in TestCafe

Tags: html, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have one dropdown which has n options values. How can I fetch all these options values and then assert them in one go in Test Cafe. I did not find anything in Documentation.
Please let me now how can I do this.

Assume I have below dropdown :

```
<select id="city">
    <option>New York</option>
    <option>London</option>
    <option>Paris</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find a similar example [in TestCafe Documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/examples-of-using-client-functions.html#complex-dom-queries) (and we're going to provide a more extended one in the near future). 
In your case you can use the following code:

```js
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Get option values`
    .page `https://example.com`;

const getOptionNames = ClientFunction(() => {
    const select  = document.querySelector('#city');
    const options = select.querySelectorAll('option');
    const values  = [];

    for (let option of options)
        values.push(option.textContent);

    return values;
});

test('test', async t => {
    await t.expect(getOptionNames()).eql(['New York', 'London', 'Paris']);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But I would really love to see this feature where i can get the array in one go rather than looping through it.

Comment: There's no such method neither in JavaScript nor in TestCafe. You can create your own helper method and use it in your tests when necessary.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is assuming that on your page there is no other `option` html items.  That they are all underneath `<select id="city"`

```
test('TestCafe - Verify all Options', async (t) => {
    const optionList = Selector('option');
    for( var i = 0; i < await optionList.count; i++){
        const optionText = await optionList.nth(i).innerText;
        // Perform some validation/comparision on the text to see if it is as you expect....
    }
})
```

Comment: Actually, I am looking for some way where we can validate all items in one go instead of looping through them.